# I need help in Pine-Script

Tags: pine-script

I am absolutely new to Pine Script, and for now I am trying to write a simple strategy.

However, I guess I am stupid, but I cannot get the following strategy done:

if the market is at least 50 points above the vwap, I want to go long as soon as it retraces to the vwap (e.g as soon as price is only 5 points above the vwap)

The same goes for short: if market is at least 50 points below the vwap and comes back to the vwap, i want to go short.

I wanted to start with something simple, but I really dont know where to start and how to type in that the price has to come from a distance of at least 50 points to the vwap.

I know, for a lot of people this sounds very dumb, but I really want to learn how to write that.

I am grateful for every answer :)

here is my code..

```
strategy("Upper Vwap", overlay=false)
upperVWAP = high - vwap(hlc3)
lowerVWAP = low - vwap(hlc3)
AAA = 0
if upperVWAP > 30
    AAA := 1
BBB = 0
if lowerVWAP < 3.5
    BBB := 1
long = AAA > 0
longCondition1 = long or long [2] or long[3] or long[4] or long[6] or long [7] or long[8] or long[9] or long[10] or long [11] or long[12] or long[13] or long[14] or long [15] or long[16] or long[17] or long[18] or long [19] or long[20] or long[21] or long[22] or long [23] or long[24] or long[25] or long[26] or long [27] or long[28] or long[29] or long[30] or long [31] or long[32] or long[33] or long[34]
UUU = 0
if lowerVWAP < 2
    UUU := 1
entry = UUU < 1
longCondition2 = entry and entry[1] and entry[2] and entry [3] and entry[4] and entry[5] and entry[6] and entry [7] and entry[8] and entry[9] and entry[10] and entry [11] and entry[12] and entry[13] and entry[14] and entry [15] and entry[16] and entry[17] and entry[18]
testlinie = 0
III = 0
if lowerVWAP <= 3.5
    III := 1
longCondition3 = III > 0
if longCondition1 and longCondition2 and longCondition3
    testlinie := 5
strategy.entry("LONG", true, 1, when = testlinie > 0)
strategy.exit("EXIT", "LONG", 1, profit = 60, loss = 30)
```

Kindest Regards

Comment: You should post the code you already have.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this as a study first? I find this often helps me. Ie, to plot a shape, bgcolor or something for my conditions. Then I figure out any strategy (entries/exits) after I get my study looking right... Hopefully that helps!

Comment: PS - I recommend you update your question title - it's way too unspecific for StackOverflow.